# mysql replacing all characters to left of specific character with a string

Tags: mysql

Is it possible in mysql to replace a character and all characters to the left with a string.

so if I have a table with

```
jonathan@abc.com
helen@123.co.uk
```

it becomes

```
www.abc.com
www.123.co.uk
```

afraid I have no idea where to begin :(

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You should start by reading the docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET email = CONCAT('www.', SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, '@', -1))
```

Comment: lol, thanks, I figured out the exact same solution at the same time, sorry to waste yours !

Answer (score 0):

I did it with

```
concat("www.",SUBSTRING_INDEX(e.email, '@', -1))
```